# Should I attempt to have a large amount of code reviewed?

Tags: discussion, code-length

I'd love it if someone out there was willing to critique my code base on a larger scale - the thing is I can't imagine why anyone would actually want to.

Do you think I'm wrong about this?  Should I try posting something like - review my entire system?

Comment: this might help http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=architecture.

Comment: I think many people would love to -- if they had the time.

Answer (score 17):

I'd do it in small pieces. Firstly post the most important part of your application then wait for a few reviews.

If somebody points out a bad practice and it exists in other parts of the application try to fix it before you post the next piece. It could be boring to see the same issues over and over.